# How to compare two strings (from user input) in a bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

Here comes my script, i know i'm doing something wrong so please help me!

```
#!/bin/bash
# Description of the script

echo "Enter first word "
read test1
echo "Enter second word "
read test2

cmp $test1 $test2 > error

total=`wc -c error | cut -f 7 -d " "`
echo $total

if [ $total -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "Both words contents are same"else
        echo "Both words contents are not same"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless you *have* to use `cmp`, you can use `[ ]` for comparison:

```
if [ "$test1" = "$test2" ]
then
        echo "Both words contents are same"
else
        echo "Both words contents are not same"
fi
```

`cmp` compares files. If, say, you entered `foo` for `test1` and `bar` for `test2`, then it will compare two files named `foo` and `bar`, which is probably not what you intended.

Aside from that, this line:

```
echo "Both words contents are same"else
```

is the same as:

```
echo "Both words contents are sameelse"
```

You should either put `else` on a different line, or put a `;` before it:

```
echo "Both words contents are same"
else
# or
echo "Both words contents are same"; else
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use cmp?  You are already using a [bash conditional](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html) later in your script, so you could swap out the cmp.  Example conditional:

```
if [ "$test1" != "$test2" ]; then
     # not equal
else
     # equal
fi
```

[Other comparison operators in bash.](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the error of using `cmp` for comparing strings where it only compares files, you have the problems that you are actually calculating the length of the error message from `cmp`, and extracting the file name, not the character count, from the output from `wc`.  The entire computation would be a lot more elegant without a temporary file; if you do use a temporary file, you should clean it out after using it.

If you really wanted to see the amount of difference between two strings, maybe pass them to `wdiff` instead.

Here is a refactored version:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Note absence of boilerplate comment

read -p "Enter first word: " test1   # Note use of read -p
read -p "Enter second word: " test2

# Note use of wdiff
# Note proper quoting of strings!  This is important
if report=$(wdiff -s123 <(echo "$test1") <(echo "$test2")); then
    echo "Strings are equal"
else
    echo "Strings differ"
    echo "$report"
fi
```

As an aside, a basic idiom with `wc` is to redirect input into it; then, it doesn't print a file name, so you don't have to postprocess it.  And lo, this also removes the need for a temporary file.

```
total=$(cmp one two | wc -c)
```

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) or perhaps even [accepting](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) it.  Thanks!